# ASP.NET Tracing "Begin Init" value larger than "End Render"

Tags: asp.net, trace

I'm trying to pinpoint an ASP.NET page performance issue and I'm running tracing. As Look at the value returned the "Begin Init" value larger than "End Render". Shouldn't the number of seconds increase for each event listed?

Here is the output example:

```
Category Message From First(s) From Last(s) 
aspx.page Begin PreInit   
aspx.page End PreInit 1.34734832226262E-05 0.000013 
aspx.page Begin Init 3.04115764167849E-05 0.000017 
aspx.page End Init 0.000133579962235751 0.000103 
aspx.page Begin InitComplete 0.000148208315448888 0.000015 
aspx.page End InitComplete 0.000158602145363486 0.000010 
aspx.page Begin PreLoad 0.000167841105287572 0.000009 
aspx.page End PreLoad 0.000180544675183191 0.000013 
aspx.page Begin Load 0.000189783635107278 0.000009 
aspx.page End Load 1.11670230723776 1.116513 
aspx.page Begin LoadComplete 1.11673502855416 0.000033 
aspx.page End LoadComplete 1.11674580734074 0.000011 
aspx.page Begin PreRender 1.116754661344 0.000009 
aspx.page End PreRender 1.1210065076924 0.004252 
aspx.page Begin PreRenderComplete 1.12102498561224 0.000018 
aspx.page End PreRenderComplete 1.12108927337505 0.000064 
aspx.page Begin SaveState 1.12280194557098 0.001713 
aspx.page End SaveState 1.12307988428203 0.000278 
aspx.page Begin SaveStateComplete 1.1230991321152 0.000019 
aspx.page End SaveStateComplete 1.12311029585844 0.000011 
aspx.page Begin Render 1.12311876490504 0.000008 
aspx.page End Render 1.12626309093254 0.003144
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't. Look at the `E-05` at the end of 3.04115764167849`E-05`

The actual value for Begin Init is:

0.0000304115764167849

Comment: Missed that, thank you. I wonder if I can format the number so that default render doesn't use scientific notation.

Comment: You would probably have to implement your own Trace Listener. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener%28v=VS.71%29.aspx I think it is probably too much effort now that are aware to look out for E-05